# How to convert this subprojects section from a groovy gradle file to a kotlin kts file?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

New to Gradle, Groovy and Kotlin and having trouble translating a groovy based gradle file to a kotlin based one.

https://github.com/square/okio/issues/647

How would I translate this below to Kotlin for a build.gradle.kts?

```
subprojects { subProject ->
  ...

  configurations.all { configuration ->
    // Workaround for kapt bug with MPP dependencies
    // https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-31641
    // https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33206
    if (name.contains('kapt') || name.contains("wire")) {
      attributes.attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, subProject.objects.named(Usage.class, Usage.JAVA_RUNTIME))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a near 1:1 translation:

```
subprojects {
    configurations.all {
        if (name.contains("kapt") || name.contains("wire")) {
            attributes.attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Usage.JAVA_RUNTIME))
        }
    }
}
```